# Catch error messages from standard PHP functions with a Unit test

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

A bit unclear on the title, but here we go.

I am running a unit test on a method that essentially runs a `strpos()`. Like this:

```
return strpos($this->getHeaderLine($headerName), $value) !== false;
```

Now I also want to see what happens if I supply it an empty value. When provide an empty string, I get the following message:

```
strpos(): Empty needle
```

This message in itself is clear enough, I don't want to throw an exception here. I do want to know if it returned this message though. How would I go about doing this or do I need to rewrite my method?

Comment: technically you could use `set_error_handler` and `restore_error_handler`. but thinking of design it's not a good choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
public function testWarning()
{
    $this->expectException(PHPUnit_Framework_Error_Warning::class);
    $this->expectExceptionMessage("Empty needle");
    strpos('meh', '');
}
```

This test passes, but if you comment out the expectations, it fails. There are more related classes in PHPUnit framework, like `PHPUnit_Framework_Error_Deprecated`, `PHPUnit_Framework_Error_Notice` and so on.